# Does Example 6.3 in Chapter 6 of Eloquent Javascript need to be this complicated?

Tags: javascript

*I will add a disclaimer that the context of this might not make sense unless you are familiar with [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/).*

In the online edition of [Eloquent Javascript (Chapter 6)](http://eloquentjavascript.net//chapter6.html), I am trying to understand the  explanation for code **example 6.3**.

The example specifically covers the **splitParagraph()** function, however I have added all the additional functions in the code example to make it work standalone at the example at the bottom of this post, but specifically I am trying to understand why the author has suggested to go the long way to find the length of the string.

The author suggests to use **A)**:

```
var end = reduce(Math.min, text.length, map(indexOrEnd, ["*", "{"]));
```

Why not just use **B)**:

```
var end = text.length;
```

I have tried to use **B)** and the results seem to be the same. I can work out what is going on with **A)**, but I don't see what the point to doing it in such a way is.

Here is the full code dump, I have made a modification at the bottom to output it if anybody copies and pastes it:

```
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}

function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}

function map(func, array) {
  var result = [];
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    result.push(func(element));
  });
  return result;
}

function splitParagraph(text) {

    function indexOrEnd(character) {
        var index = text.indexOf(character);
        return index == -1 ? text.length : index;
    }

    function takeNormal() {
        var end = reduce(Math.min, text.length, map(indexOrEnd, ["*", "{"]));
        var part = text.slice(0, end);
        text = text.slice(end);
        return part;
    }

    function takeUpTo(character) {
        var end = text.indexOf(character, 1);
        if (end == -1)
            throw new Error("Missing closing '" + character + "'");

        var part = text.slice(1, end);
        text = text.slice(end + 1);

        return part;
    }

  var fragments = [];

  while (text != "") {
    if (text.charAt(0) == "*")
      fragments.push({type: "emphasised", content: takeUpTo("*")});
    else if (text.charAt(0) == "{")
      fragments.push({type: "footnote", content: takeUpTo("}")});
    else
      fragments.push({type: "normal", content: takeNormal()});
  }
  return fragments;
}

console.log(splitParagraph("hello world"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using **method A** break the string at the occurrences of `{` or `*`. so splitParagraph function will break a text containing those character.

i.e.

```
var x = splitParagraph("Hello boy *you're the best* friend {for me}");
```

x will contain

```
[
  { type: "normal", content "hello boy " },
  { type: "emphasised", content "you're the best" },
  { type: "normal", content " friend " },
  { type: "footnote", content "for me" }
]
```

using **method B** x will contain

```
[
  { type: "normal", content "Hello boy *you're the best* friend {for me}" }
]
```